# My ASP.NET Core MVC application stopped saving changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.NET Core MVC application (written in C#) stopped for some reason to save changes in database.

It reads perfectly and there is no any error related to connection itself. It worked perfectly yesterday but today it is not longer working. What is going on in here? Could it be related to a "refresh" problem.

This is my controller code:

```
// POST: Approver/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind] Approver approver)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbContext.UpdateApprover(approver);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dbContext);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my CONTEXT update method:

```
public void UpdateApprover(Approver approver)
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stored_procedure_update", con)
            {
                CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", approver.CODE);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAIL", approver.MAIL);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", approver.NAME);

         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
     }
}
```

Am I missing something?

---

CONNECTION FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MyApplication.Models;

namespace MyApplication.Context
{
    public class Connection
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog = ''; Persist Security Info=True;User ID = ''; Password='xxxxxx'";

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public IEnumerable<Approver> GetAllApprovers()
        {
            var ApproversList = new List<Approver>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetAllApprovers", con)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    var Approver = new Approver
                    {
                        CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString()),
                        MAIL = dr["MAIL"].ToString(),
                        FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString(),
                        LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString()
                    };

                    ApproversList.Add(Approver);
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            return ApproversList;

        }

        public void UpdateApprover(Approver Approver)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Update_Approver", con)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", Approver.CODE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAIL", Approver.MAIL);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", Approver.FIRSTNAME);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", Approver.LASTNAME);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }


        }

        public Approver GetApproverById(int? id)
        {
            var Approver = new Approver();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetapproverById", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", id);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    Approver.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
                    Approver.MAIL = dr["MAIL"].ToString();
                    Approver.FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString();
                    Approver.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            return Approver;

        }


    }
}
```

CONTROLLER FILE:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApplication.Context;
using MyApplication.Models;

namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerApprover : Controller
    {
        readonly Connection dbContext = new Connection();

        // GET: Approver
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Approver> ApproversList = dbContext.GetAllApprovers().ToList();
            return View(ApproversList);
        }

        // GET: Approver/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Approver approver = dbContext.GetApproverById(id);
            return View(approver);
        }

        // GET: Approver/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Approver/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(int id, [Bind] Approver approver)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.UpdateApprover(Approver);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Approver/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Approver Approver = dbContext.GetApproverById(id);
            return View(approver);
        }

        // POST: Approver/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind] Approver approver)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.UpdateApprover(approver);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My appsettings.json:

```
  {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the comment section, but I can't comment right now, need 50 reputation. But I think, you could try first see if there is an error on your catch block, change it to `catch (Exception e)` to see if there is something there. Log it, or put a breakpoint in debugging mode.

Comment: Also, add a try catch block in your update method `try { } catch(Exception e) { }`

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying.
Do you see something wrong in my code?

Comment: You said its working perfectly yesterday. It should today. Just always try to log exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, that's really strange. I'm checking it out

Comment: Is it necessary to declare the 'e' variable?

Comment: you can name it whatever you want, but it's necessary, there you can get the error messages or the exceptions.

Comment: Except for this code, can you update the database in the database client?

Answer (score 0):

Correctly pick your connection string and change your CONTEXT method to something like that, if still not work.

```
private IConfiguration Configuration;
public HomeController(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        Configuration = _configuration;
    }





public void UpdateApprover(Approver approver)
{

  string connectionString=  Configuration.GetConnectionString("YOUR CONNECTION STRING NAME");
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
       con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stored_procedure_update", con))
            {
                CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", approver.CODE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAIL", approver.MAIL);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", approver.NAME);

         
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
            }
     }
}
```

---

CONNECTION FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MyApplication.Models;

namespace MyApplication.Context
{
    public class Connection
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog = ''; Persist Security Info=True;User ID = ''; Password='xxxxxx'";

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public IEnumerable<Approver> GetAllApprovers()
        {
            var ApproversList = new List<Approver>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetAllApprovers", con)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    var Approver = new Approver
                    {
                        CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString()),
                        MAIL = dr["MAIL"].ToString(),
                        FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString(),
                        LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString()
                    };

                    ApproversList.Add(Approver);
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            return ApproversList;

        }

        public void UpdateApprover(Approver Approver)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Update_Approver", con)
                {
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", Approver.CODE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAIL", Approver.MAIL);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", Approver.FIRSTNAME);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", Approver.LASTNAME);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }


        }

        public Approver GetApproverById(int? id)
        {
            var Approver = new Approver();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetapproverById", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", id);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    Approver.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
                    Approver.MAIL = dr["MAIL"].ToString();
                    Approver.FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString();
                    Approver.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();
                }

                con.Close();
            }

            return Approver;

        }


    }
}
```

CONTROLLER FILE:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyApplication.Context;
using MyApplication.Models;

namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerApprover : Controller
    {
        readonly Connection dbContext = new Connection();

        // GET: Approver
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Approver> ApproversList = dbContext.GetAllApprovers().ToList();
            return View(ApproversList);
        }

        // GET: Approver/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Approver approver = dbContext.GetApproverById(id);
            return View(approver);
        }

        // GET: Approver/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Approver/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(int id, [Bind] Approver approver)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.UpdateApprover(Approver);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Approver/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Approver Approver = dbContext.GetApproverById(id);
            return View(approver);
        }

        // POST: Approver/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind] Approver approver)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.UpdateApprover(approver);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My appsettings.json:

```
  {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"}
```

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!
I do not fully understad, how should i modify my appsetting.json?

Comment: @programming_amazing I mean, no need to modify your appsettings.json file. you have to pick your connection string the right way, above code, I clarify that. then I  think this issue will be solved.

Comment: I do not understand the part that it asks me to write the "YOUR CONNECTION STRING NAME". Where did a declare that?

Comment: Go to your appsettings.json file and know your connection string name. for example: ```"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb1;User Id=TestUser;Password=TestPswd;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}    ```    here your connectionstring name is :- DefaultConnection.

Comment: Pal, got another question: where should i use this: public HomeController(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        Configuration = _configuration;
    }?

Comment: you could not give your controller name. so I assume your controller name is a home controller. if your controller name is another, so you should change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229102/discussion-between-brett-lee-and-programming-amazing).

Comment: I would put a try catch block around your code within UpdateApprover() method. If the code worked before, it shouldn't stop working lol. See if there is an exception happening. Double check your connection string and your stored procedure. Also, as a general note, I would recommend using a library like Dapper or EntityFramework for database access.